# Java: What's incorrect with my general tree traversal implementation?

Tags: java, tree

I've been tasked with finding and returning a particular node from a general tree given by the string `targetName`. Take a look at my implementation below:

```
public GeneralTreeNode findNode(String targetName) {          
    if (this.name.equals(targetName)) {
        return this;
    } else {
        for (GeneralTreeNode child : this.children) {
            return child.findNode(targetName);
        }
    }
    // no node containing the string could be found
    return null;  
  }
```

The only problem is that this too often seems to incorrectly return null when in fact a node does exist. It's as if the last line, `return null`, is too greedy.

Chucking a few breakpoints on this and watching it shows it only seems to go down to the lowest depth until a node has no children, in which case it simply returns null.

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: You need to check the return value of findNode and only return if it is *not* null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
public GeneralTreeNode findNode(String targetName) {          
    if (this.name.equals(targetName)) {
        return this;
    } else {
        for (GeneralTreeNode child : this.children) {
            GeneralTreeNode childResult = child.findNode(targetName);

            if (childResult != null) {
                return childResult;       // only return if you really found something
            }
        }
    }

    // no node containing the string could be found
    return null;  
}
```

You only want to return the result from the child search if it really found something.

Comment: Eliminating the `return null` statement will cause a compilation error, wouldn't it? This opens up the possibility of no value being returned.

Comment: @EchoLogic I was pretty specific with "change this part". No need to copy the code that didn't change, I'd think. But it doesn't hurt either. Thanks Tim.

Comment: that's fine, thank you for your help. It's looking good. Obviously I'm underestimating the importance of null checks when dealing with recursive methods. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The readability of the code disappears if you implement in this way. Tree-traversal would be better implemented in an helper class and you pass the ROOT element with the target_name together.

If you return null in this way, it is something like node is null actually it is not. On the other hand, when you use "doer" or "processor" method/function, it can return true saying "I cannot find anything".

Still, your code seems ok. I just rewrite it.

```
static Node search(Node node, String nodeName) {
   if (node.getName().equals(nodeName)) return node;

   List<Node> children = node.getChildren();
   foreach(Node child : children) { 
      Node resultChild = search(child, nodeName);
      if (resutlChild != null) return resultChild;

   }

   return null;

}
```

Comment: `foreach` this is not a java syntax.

Comment: This is just coding on paper, for or foreach trying to tell it is looping :)

Comment: you should be writing like this: `for(Node child : children) {`.

Comment: Yup very true.  Should be different than C#